# Avoiding respond to a bots

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on discord bot and making ping command as test, but it loops because it responds to itself. However, if I put `message.author.bot === false` in every command my code will be a mess!

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.content === "ping" && message.author.bot === false){
    message.channel.send("pong")
  } else if(message.content === "pong" && message.author.bot === false){
    message.channel.send("ping")
  }
})
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `if(message.author.bot) return;` after `client.on("message", message => {` and as result get:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content === "ping" && message.author.bot === false){
    message.channel.send("pong")
  } else if(message.content === "pong" && message.author.bot === false){
    message.channel.send("ping")
  }
})
```

to ignore messages from bots

Comment: but i still need to put `&& message.author.bot === false` ?

Comment: @Sussy nope, it should totally help you if you add it only once, but add it as I told you

Comment: ahh i see thank you!

Comment: @Sussy np, try this code and please mark my answer as correct if it helped you!

Comment: i will wait for few minutes to mark.

Comment: @Sussy Glad I helped you, and thanks!